# React passing import name as prop and adding to image src

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component which has a prop passed with the name of an Import which contains an image path.

In this case the prop value is **Ico1**.

I need to pass the prop in the img src like so:

code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import Ico1 from '../icon1.png';


 const MyComp = (props) => <div>

           <img src={props.chosenicon} alt="" />

         </div> 
     }

 </div>

 export default MyComp
```

My problem is that when I add this:

```
<img src={Ico1} alt="" />
```

...it shows the image but if I do this:

```
<img src={props.chosenicon} alt="" />
```

...it shows no image, even though the value of `props.chosenicon` is '`Ico1`' and typeof says they are both strings.

How can I get this to work so it shows the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two components - App.js and Icon.js and an image called icon.jpg

Here is your App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import icon from './icon.jpg';
import Icon from './Icon';

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>This is the app</h1>
    <Icon icon={icon} />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

And here is your Icon.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Icon = props => (
  <div>
    <p>This is the icon</p>
    <img src={props.icon} alt="" />
  </div>
);

export default Icon;
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/4z64wyqnn9

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your current approach is that the final HTML is

```
<img src="Ico1" alt="" />
```

That's not going to work obviously.
When you import a PNG file, the relative location is translated into a full URL. So you need to make sure that what ends up as `src` is actually `Ico1`, which is a string just like `"Ico1"` but will be something like `https://example.com/app/icon1.png`.

You can either move the `import` line to the parent component, then pass the image along like so:

```
<MyComp chosenicon={Ico1}/>
```

If you want to keep the image file imports inside `MyComp`, you need to translate the string `"Ico1"` you've received in the `props` to the actual URL. One way is to add this to your `MyComp.js`:

```
const icons = { Ico1, Ico2 }; // no keys stated, so they are "Ico1" and "Ico2"
```

Now you can use

```
const MyComp = props => (
  <div>
    <img src={icons[props.chosenicon]} alt="" />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try passing the image path as the prop, so `props.chosenIcon` will be `../icon1.png` instead of `Ico1`. I think your problem may be that `Ico1` is passed by reference rather than by value.

Answer (score 0):

***Your App.js should be like this:***

```
import "./styles.css";
import Home from "./Home";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}
```

***Here is the imported image with props:***

```
import icon from "./icon.jpg";

const Home = () => {
  const list = [
    { title: "icon1", logo: icon, alt: "icon1", id: 1 },
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {list.map((list) => (
        <div key={list.id}>
          <h1>{list.title}</h1>
          <img className="class" src={list.logo} alt={list.alt} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**you see full in here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/image-props-37zo4**

Answer (score 0):

**You can just pass the props like this and it should work**

```
<Icon icon={require("./icon.jpg")} />
```