# Loading and rendering an image in react with a passed image url through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that is mean to render an image. Withing the functional component, I am passing in the images relative path from the file. I want to simple render the image in the url browser. I did read that I should be using `require`. When I try to render it, it shows that the image is not there and the empty image icon. I am not sure what else to do. here is my component.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function PropertyImage({ image }) {
  console.log(image)
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={require(image)}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have also tried:

```
export default function PropertyImage({ image }) {
  console.log(image)
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={image}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the relative path that I have which is what image shows in the console.log:

```
../images/unnamed.jpeg
```

Here is the file structure.

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oFHi.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52999501/3687878 - please search before posting questions

Comment: Simple method is add your images to public folder(/public/images/yourimage.png) and then you can use it inside  any component directly without any require or import. `<img src="/images/youtimage.png" />`

Comment: @sojin thank you it worked. It makes sense.

Comment: You are welcome @omarjandali